# .htaccess to access the file but to ignore non existing directory in URL path for that file

Tags: .htaccess

I have my htaccess and it already does couple of good things (it hides www and .php in my url) but I also need to add one additional feature to it.

I have the main domain called: wdd.ie

I have a root folder called: wdd.ie

Most important files are kept in the root.

I have also the following file in the root: about.php

I love to access about.php file by calling non existing directory: www.wdd.ie/myweb/

And my full URL path looks like this: www.wdd.ie/myweb/about

I would like to access the file (stored in the root) to allow non existing directory in url but to ignore it

Could anyone help!? Please, please help!

As this new desired htaccess feature complexity is now probably beyond my skills.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [L,QSA]
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly you want the following url **www.wdd.ie/myweb/about** to offer up content from **www.wdd.ie/about.php** but keep the url the same?

If so, then the following should work

`RewriteRule ^myweb/about$ /about.php [L]`

Comment: Thank you for answering, 

What would be the rewrite condition for this rule then?

What I want is www.wdd.ie/myweb/about to be kept fully in the url but the problem is that my about.php file has to remain in the root folder. Because that directory www.wdd.ie/myweb/ doesn't realy exists and it only serves as a variable for my url path.

Comment: The rule I posted in my answer should do what you're asking. It doesn't matter that */myweb/* doesn't exist. The rule above is handling that. As long as there are no other rules that interfere with it.

Comment: I am trying to test your RewriteRule but for every RewriteRule there must be RewriteCond stated. I will be happy to implement your answer but I don't know what is the RewriteCond for the rule you have suggested. And this is where I am stuck.

Comment: Where did you read that? That information is not correct. It's the other way round. If you have a `RewriteCond` you should have a `RewriteRule`. You may have as many `RewriteRule`'s as you wish without a single `RewriteCond`

Comment: I don't know what do we do wrong but for the moment when I add this RewriteRule ^myweb/about$ /about.php [L] to the top of my existing .htaccess and when I click here  http://wdd.ie/myweb/about nothing changes and the about.php file isn't being executed at all

Comment: I have just now tested your rule on different file called test.php and it looks like it is working! That probably means that I have to look now back to my php code. Thank you in advance for that rule!